# Which Pokemon Go fast move is this from Rocket's Porygon/Porygon2/Porygon-Z?

Tags: pokemon-go

Sometimes Team Go Rocket uses a Porygon, Porygon2 or Porygon-Z with the fast move shown in the picture. Which move is it? There are features unusual to it:

- It looks like an Electric-type attack from the animation, however, it states it is not very effective against Tyranitar, whereas Electric-type moves are neutral against Tyranitar.
- Despite it stating that the move is not very effective, it deals a large amount of damage for a fast move (more than a quarter of Tyranitar's health), even considering Porygon-Z's very high CP. Porygon's fast moves are Lock-On, Charge Beam, and Hidden Power, though I wouldn't expect this much damage from any of those moves except a super-effective Hidden Power.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could it be a normal typed Hidden Power? It would get STAB and be not very effective against a TTar. Not sure about the animation though

Comment: Nevermind, I just read that Hidden Power cannot have the Normal type.

Comment: Even if it were normal, it shouldn’t deal >25% of Tyranitar’s HP

Comment: I tested three different hidden power types (dark, ghost, and electric) and they all had the same animation which looked like an electric move. PorygonZ had a fairly high attack stat, and with that 20% shadow attack boost (not sure if it applies to Team Rocket), so not very effective most can deal some hefty damage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opposing Hidden Power in a Team GO Rocket battle (or raid) is [always Fighting-type](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Hidden_Power_(move)#Pok.C3.A9mon_GO). It is also bugged in that [it states "not very effective" based on whether the opponent resists Normal-type or not](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphArena/comments/ivx2of/hidden_power_never_super_effective/g5xw3ce?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), not the actual type of the move (in fact, it can never be Normal-type). It also always has the same Electric-type animation regardless of its type (thank you Wondercricket). And it can deal a large amount of damage to Tyranitar because it is 4x super-effective, whereas none of Porgyon's other moves are super-effective.

So the move is Hidden Power Fighting.